# Heap block at X modified at Y past requested size - freeing allocated memory

Tags: c, memory, free

Program crashing when freeing allocated memory: "Heap block at X modified at Y past requested size of 21".

Running function getUstr, crashes on free(uStr).
Can someone please help me find where am I using unallocated memory?
Thank you!

```
int HexToUChars(char* hexStr, unsigned char **str){
    int i, n;
    int strLen = strlen(hexStr)/2;

    for (i = 0; i < (int)strLen; i++) {

        sscanf_s(hexStr + 2 * i*sizeof(unsigned char), "%02X", *str+i*sizeof(unsigned char));
    }

    return 0;
}

int getUStr(){
    char *hexStr = "E7CA7905DD060F0E437C885BF13DED9243B1D2BD94CB11223DA71360A8F7D2D4";
    unsigned char *uStr;
    size_t strLen = (size_t)strlen(hexStr) / 2;
    uStr = calloc((strLen + 1), sizeof(unsigned char));
    if (uStr != NULL){
        HexToUChars(hexStr, &uStr);
        free(uStr);//Error : Heap block at X modified at Y past requested size of 21
    }
}
```

Comment: uStr is already a pointer, and the function HexToUChars() is not changing that address, so the only result of passing the address of uStr to is complication in the code.

Comment: Originally had the memory allocated in the HexToUChars function, that’s why I passed  it in as pointer to pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `sscanf()` and friends, `%02X` expects a pointer to an `unsigned int`, but you're giving it a pointer to an `unsigned char`. If an `unsigned int` is, say, 4 bytes on your system, then you're going to write past the end of your allocated memory on the last couple of iterations through that loop.

You should provide a pointer to a (local) `unsigned int` to `sscanf_s()`, and then assign the value of that to your `unsigned char`.

Comment: Thanks.
Declared unsigned int n, and updated loop:

`   sscanf_s(hexStr + 2 * i, "%02X", &n);
  (*str)[i] = (unsigned char)n;`

Answer (score 0):

```
there were several errors in the presented code.
those errors are fixed here
I did add a few $includes, etc so the file would compile


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int HexToUChars( const char *, unsigned char * );
int getUStr( void );

int HexToUChars(const char* pHexStr, unsigned char *pStr)
{
    int i = 0; // loop index
    //int n;  // this raises a compiler warning about unused variable
    // the strLen is using a reserved word, with only a capitalization change,
    // I.E. very poor program practice
    int hexStrLen = (int)strlen(pHexStr) >> 1;  // this assumes that hexStr is an even number of bytes

    for (i = 0; i < hexStrLen; i++)
    {
        pStr[i] =  pHexStr[2*i] - '0';
        pStr[i] += pHexStr[(2*i)+1] - '0';
    } // end for

    return 1;
} // end function: HexToUChars

int getUStr()
{
    const char* pHexStr = "E7CA7905DD060F0E437C885BF13DED9243B1D2BD94CB11223DA71360A8F7D2D4";
    unsigned char *pStr;

    int  hexStrLen = strlen(pHexStr) / 2;

    if( NULL == (pStr = calloc( (hexStrLen + 1), sizeof(unsigned char) ) ) )
    {
        perror( "calloc failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, calloc successful


    HexToUChars(pHexStr, pStr);
    if( strlen((const char*)pStr) != hexStrLen )
    {
        perror( "problem in HexToUChars");
    }
    printf( "%s", pStr );

    free(pStr);

    return(0); // without this, compiler raises warning about no return statement
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to help. I'll take into account your comments (need to brush off some dust from my c...). The result pStr didn't return the value expected.